# Pseudo-inverse matrix to minimise $L^1$ norm error

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, error-function, pseudoinverse

Given the over-determined linear system $A\cdot x = b$, the least-squares solution (minimise $||A\cdot x - b||_2$) can be obtained by matrix multiplication:
$$x_\text{ls} = A^\dagger \cdot b $$
where $A^\dagger = (A^T A)^{-1}A^T$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse.

The solution that minimises the sum of absolute residuals (minimise the $L^1$-norm $||A\cdot x - b||_1$) can be formulated as a linear programming problem as [1]:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{minimise} & \mathbf{1}^T t \\
\text {subject to } & -t \preceq A x-b \preceq t
\end{array}
$$

Why is it not possible to define a "pseudoinverse" matrix that gives the minimum $L^1$-norm solution, as $A^\dagger$ does for the minimum $L^2$-norm solution?

[1] *Boyd, Stephen; Vandenberghe, Lieven*, [**Convex optimization.**](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-83378-7/hbk). xiii, 716 p. (2004). [ZBL1058.90049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1058.90049).

Comment: There’s no reason to expect that this would be possible.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Can it be shown why this is possible for the L2-norm? Are there other Lp-norms with this property?

Comment: What we are essentially finding is the minimum distance between a vector b and a convex set: $C=\{y:y=Ax, \exists x\}$. With the L2 norm we have a Hilbert space. The problem of minimizing the distance between a vector and a convex set always has a unique solution in a Hilbert space. Uniqueness is not guaranteed in these problems when we are just looking at a Banach space...ie other Lp spaces.

Comment: It helps to be familiar with the “four subspaces” picture emphasized by Gilbert Strang. Let $T:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be a linear transformation. The pseudoinverse of $T$ is by definition the function $S:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ defined as follows. If $b \in \mathbb R^m$ then $S(b)$ is the least norm solution to $T(x) = \hat b$, where $\hat b$ is the projection of $b$ onto $R(T)$. In other words, $S(b)$ is the unique vector $x \in R(T^*)$ which satisfies $T(x) = \hat b$. With this description of the pseudoinverse, you can convince yourself that $S$ is a linear transformation.